# Using 2 classes for a Comission Calculator in Java

Tags: java, class

I am doing an assignment for a beginning Java class. We have to write a commission calculator and use two classes in it. I am stuck on how to use variables from one class in a second class. The methods that i have found so far are not working for me. Any advice would be greatly helpful. Below is the code i have so far.

```js
package calc;

/**
 *
 * @author Ethan
 */
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
 Scanner calcu = new Scanner(System.in); //Creats the scanner used for Input
  //Sets all of the variables to be used
 double sal; //salary
  double com1; //Comission percentage
  double com2; // Find the ammount of comisssion from yearly sales
  double comp; //Yearly Sales
  double frac; //Decimal Comission form
  double total; // Total of Compensation of Yearly salary + Comission
          
    System.out.println("Enter the annual Salary here: ");
    sal = calcu.nextDouble();
    
    System.out.println("Enter the total Sales here: ");
    comp = calcu.nextDouble();
    
   Rate();
frac = com1/100; //converts the Sales Comission to a decimal
 com2 = frac * comp; // Find the total Comission based on the 
  total = sal + com2; //find the total compensation
  
  System.out.print("Your total compensation is " + total);
    
    }
private static void Rate(){
     // Rate of commission is determined below.
        if (comp < 10000)
           com1 = 20;            //20% commission rate
        else if (comp < 30000)
           com1 = 22;             // 22% commission rate
        else if (comp < 50000)
           com1 = 23;            // 23% commission rate
        else if (comp < 100000)
           com1 = 24;            // 24% commission rate
        else
           com1 = 25;            // 25% commission rate
    
}
    
}
```

The problem i have is the i can't pull the rates so they can be used in the calculations.

Comment: Where's your second class, and what are you trying to do with it?  (You don't seem to actually _have_ a second class, since the `new` keyword only appears in your code once, and that's to create a `Scanner` instance.)  Also, I'm not sure I understand your intent...  As a general rule, you're not _supposed_ to use variables from one class in another.  In fact, one reason to create a new class is to prevent exactly that kind of (ab)use.

Answer (score 0):

A few major issues on your code.  Your code is encapsulated in the Calc class, but no constructor is ever called.  (eg. new Calc()).  Rate() is a method in Calc, so it would be called by Calc.Rate().  Check out a few more examples of how to construct a java class, and you will understand encapsulation of your variables.

Comment: Thanks. the instructor is not very good and just gives us a project to work on, then does his own things so its been hard to learn anything. I can get it to run just fine inside of one method just fine

Answer (score 0):

You only have posted one class so far. Where is the second? You will need to make sure both classes are in separate files as well.

```
public class Class1(){
    //Class variables
    public int myPublicInt;   //public variables are accessable to any class that calls it
    private int myPrivateInt; //private variables can not be modified outside of the class

    //Class constructor, this is used to create objects of a class
    public Class1(){
        myPublicInt = 0;
        myPrivateInt = 1;
    }

    //Now we have setter and getter methods to handle private variables

    public void setMyPrivateInt(int newValue){
        myPrivateInt = newValue;
    }

    public void getMyPrivateInt(){
        return myPrivateInt;
    }

    //lastly this is a private method, only Class1 objects can call this method
    //internally, so we can call it in our constructor but not from Class2
    private void somePrivateMethod(){
        //does something
    }
```

}

So Now you will have some first class, it has some data and some methods and a constructor. Making variables public is not a good idea for the security of your code, you will want to make your second program create an object of the first one to access its variables and method calls. See the below program.

```
public class Class2{

//Class Variables, declares an object of the first class
private Class1 myClassObject;

//Constructor for this class, instantiates the first class object
public Class2(){
    myClassObject = new Class1();
}

//Main method and runtime of our program
public static void main(String args[]){
    Class2 thisClass = new Class2();

    thisClass.printMyPrivateIntFromClass1();
}

//Method from this class, Class2
public void printMyPrivateIntFromClass1(){
    System.out.println(myClassObject.getMyPrivateInt());
}
```

}

So in the second class we make an object of the first one, this way we can manipulate and use that object, its data and its methods. Notice that I used constructors to make objects of each class. When you call that object you can also call its public methods and variables. Again I would not recommend making variables public because then they are too easy to manipulate. If you have public methods that lead to your variables you can use those as a safer way to change or access the data stored in them.  Hope this helps explain using a class inside another.

A couple of other notes, work on indentation, you should use the same indentation for code nested on the same level, and anything nested underneath something else by use of {} should be indented in once more so that code is more readable for you and others.